# combining an if and sum statement - possibly using countif

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, countif

Can I please ask for assistance here.

I have an alphabetical sorted row of names (row A) and I want to know numerically how many times they appear and  total in row B. (Running  total or not)!

I believe the logic would be something like this
IF(A1=A2) SUM B1+1 to B2 ELSE B2 =1
I can't see any excel statement that assists in accomplishing this.

Thank you in advance of anyone commenting on this problem.

```
+------------------+----+
| Cersei Lannister | 1  |
| Cersei Lannister | 2  |
| Jon Snow         | 1  |
| Petyr Baelish    | 1  |
| Jorah Mormont    | 1  |
| Sansa Stark      | 1  |
| Arya Stark       | 1  |
| Arya Stark       | 2  |
| Arya Stark       | 3  |
+------------------+----+
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the table you're using? Also, the [AutoSum](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-AutoSum-to-sum-numbers-543941E7-E783-44EF-8317-7D1BB85FE706) function might already accomplish what you're trying to do, since it's also capable of counting.

Comment: @RubbelDieKatz Screenshots are not recommended. A textual representation is far better and can be added directly to the question.

Comment: Cersei Lannister 1
Cersei Lannister 2
Jon Snow 1
Petyr Baelish 1
Jorah Mormont 1
Sansa Stark 1
Arya Stark 1
Arya Stark 2
Arya Stark 3

Comment: Cersei Lannister 1
Cersei Lannister 2
Jon Snow 1
Petyr Baelish 1
Jorah Mormont 1
Sansa Stark 1
Arya Stark 1
Arya Stark 2
Arya Stark 3

Comment: Sorry it's not tabbing!

Comment: Cersei Lannister 1

Cersei Lannister
 2
Jon Snow 1
Petyr Baelish 1

Jorah Mormont
 1
Sansa Stark 1
Arya Stark 1
Arya Stark 2
Arya Stark 3

Best I can do by cut and paste. Thanks

Comment: Previously I've just used =SUM(B1+1) for the whole wSheet and then manually restarted the totals when I saw a new name. But this wsheet has over 4400 entries, and of course I'd like to do it properly! Thanks

Comment: Try http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for  your table.  Edit your original question rather than adding it as a comment.  Probably best to delete the comments to.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data you've provided you need `COUNTIF`.

With the first item in your list in cell A1, in B1 use `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)` and drag down.

The range reference is a combination of relative and absolute referencing.  As you drag down $A$1 will stay as $A$1, while A1 while update as you drag down:

**$A$1:A1

$A$1:A2

$A$1:A3,** etc...

Comment: Thankyou Darren. It works perfectly. I had tried contif before but couldn't work the logic. I'm most grateful to you..

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as the accepted answer.